# How to terminate loop while continuing program correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically I want my program to get input, which is already done, but I want it not to let a certain friend, and only this friend, not use the program. I have changed my friends actual name to "Friends Name" for obvious reasons. Right now, when I enter his name it prints `Unauthorized user detected` and prompts me to re-enter, which is what I want.

**The issue comes in when I re-enter the same friend's name**. I would like the program to print that it's once again an unauthorized user and that the program will terminate. But I can only get the program to terminate after the second name entry no matter what, or I can indent the `quit()` command 4 more spaces and the program proceeds to skip the quit command and run the rest of the program.

```
while True:
    user_input == ("Friends Name")
    print("Unauthorized user detected.")
    input("Please enter a new name: ")
    if input != "Friends Name":
        break
    else:  
        print("Unauthorized user detected, the program will now terminate.")
    quit()
```

Comment: You might want to know that this line does not do anything: `user_input == ("Friends Name")`

Comment: `while True` will not repeat ever, because you have `quit()` at its end. Remove that.

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python loop control", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.  You just need to work through those tutorials.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing educational materials.

Comment: You might want to spend some more time with the tutorials (or find new tutorials), as there are a number of problems with your code.

Comment: You  are not saving the user input to the input variable.

Comment: Thanks guys. I understand I need to continue to go through tutorials. I mentioned I was just working on something in my free time at work from what I had already learned. I cant play video tutorials here at work. I do those at night. Either way, I have made it work thanks to @ApprenticeHacker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do iteration count in a while loop is to use a variable that counts the number of times your friend's name has been entered. Also `quit()` ends the loop, remove that.

```
counter = 0
while True:
    name = input("Please enter you name")
    if name == "Friends Name":
        counter += 1
        if counter == 2:
            break 
            # or exit() if you want to program to quit in spite of code present later
```

Comment: For an hour I thought the loop will just keep asking for input and never get to the `if` condition. Then I realised its python. Please use `from __future__ import braces` :}